# In airflow, can we set jinja2 strings into `task_id`?

Tags: jinja2, airflow

**Question:**

Can I use jinja2 string syntax into `task_id` string or we are limited to `f-string`?

**Example:**

Let's say I use a `BashOperator` and inside I have assigned `params`. I can use successfully these `params` into my `bash_command`, however once I use them into the `task_id` string, I get the following error:

`airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: The key (my_task_id_string{{ params.paramname1}}{{ params.paramname2}}) has to be made of alphanumeric characters, dashes, dots and underscores`

Instead, in order to mitigate this, I use an f-string instead like so: `f"my_task_id_string{paramname1}{paramname2}"`

Comment: I've never used `Jinja` but my best guess is that `Jinja` for `task_id` is **NOT possible** since Jinja gets during **execution** and not during **scheduling** (for the same reason why you can't determine structure of your `DAG` based on output of a previous, i.e., *upstream* task). This *could* change with [AIP-12](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-12+Persist+DAG+into+DB), so keep a watch on it's [discussion](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/2575131a6bfd877bf9b43c783bdc65a085ecac705976d3d8a7c73647@%3Cdev.airflow.apache.org%3E)

Comment: Can you post your DAG code? If you're trying to use the airflow macros inside your DAG it will not work since, as @y2k-shubham has already mentioned: jinja template rendering gets done at the time of execution and not at scheduling time.

Answer (score 0):

Not all the parameters in the BashOperator is templated, the same applies for all the operators available in Airflow.

For the BashOperator the fields that Jinja will template on are `bash_command` and `env`.

For further reference, you can always refer to any operators source doc-strings, which will indicate if the field is templatable.

For BashOperator, you can refer here https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/operators/bash_operator.html